# How can I get real id of an HTML element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get the real (unchanged) id of an HTML element. I mean for example I have this line of HTML:

```html
<p id='1'>Something in paragraph</p>
```

If the user uses developer tools in Chrome or some other browser and changes the id of this `<p>` tag to '2', how can I get the past (and real) id of this element?

I used this, but it still gives the changed id.

```
 $("input").attr('id');
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Once the ID is changed you can't get the element by its original ID

Comment: @ahmedg you can't get that ID again, since your ID selectors works on the current DOM structure. If it has changed, we can't expect to get it back.

Comment: Maybe you can store link for it. Create some object like "a cache of app"

Comment: @AlonEitan and "Nish" Understand.  Thanks!

Comment: @Isa "a cache of app" is pretty complicated to do for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is very simple, just need to revise the basics of Time Travel and DOM ([Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction))

When the user changes value of id from '1' to '2' actually you have traveled from a time where `id=1` to `id=2` '1' has been erased from from existence by the user, in present value of id is '2' ( real value ), dom is only aware about this value. So you can only get those value to which dom is actually aware of i.e. only present values

```
$("input").attr('id');
```

This is the correct way to get the value of id

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a `data-id` element to the html element to get the original value.

```js
 $("p").attr("id", 2);

 console.log($("p").attr('id'));
 console.log($("p").data('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="1" data-id="1">Something in paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of original ID before changing it, you can assign that old ID to the data attribute of an element or in your code as a variable.